# Interpolating a smaller array into a larger array and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a way to interpolate data in a larger array into a smaller array or vice versa?

If for example I have an array with 137 elements of data in it and I want to size that data up into an array with 2000 elements. At the same time I want to interpolate the 137 values so they fit evenly across the 2000 elements in the new array. I therefore need some sort of interpolation / sampling mechanism, a bit like resizing an image in an arbitrary fashion.

Does anyone have an algorithms that can achieve this?

Many thanks,

Damien

Comment: There are *probably* algorithms existing for that... And algorithms waiting to be designed. But how can we know which one will fit your actual need ? It's like for images ... You can resize by leaving everything blank, or try to stretch the picture, etc.. As it stands, I think the question is too broad to be fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Algorithm that creates Perlin Noise might be useful to you. It does fit your (very broad) description. All you would need to do is to simplify it from 2D to 1D. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Algorithm_detail

Comment: The simplest is linear interpolation. But maybe you need a Spline or another smoothing algorithm. You didn't specify any requirements .

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far, sorry I should have been a bit more specific on the nature of the interpolation. I'm not after anything that's super clever, so really just a simple linear interpolation will be fine. I'm thinking something along the lines of resizing an image without any smoothing as it's not necessary for my application.

Answer (score 0):

I found and adapted this piece of code:

```
void Interpolate(float[] destination, int destFrom, int destTo, float valueFrom, float valueTo)
    {
        int destLength = destTo - destFrom;
        float valueLength = valueTo - valueFrom;
        for (int i = 0; i <= destLength; i++)
            destination[destFrom + i] = valueFrom + (valueLength * i) / destLength;
    }
```

which works perfectly for my needs.